# Gitlab-runner CI timing issues

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, gitlab-ci

Using Gitlab's CI for automatically running unit tests, I ran into an issue where a particular test case would *sometimes* fail **only** on the gitlab-runner and **never** in my development environment. When something is not running deterministically, I worry and wanna get to the bottom of it.

Here is the test case in question, note that timing is critical:

```
def test_get_file_url(self):
    # 1. get pre-signed URL to file
    expiration = 3
    url = s3.get_file_url(file_default.key, expires=expiration)

    # 2. download file contents, make sure contents match expectation
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content
    self.assertEqual(content, file_default.bytes)

    # 3. sleep long enough for URL to expire
    time_to_sleep = expiration * 4
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
    end_time = time.time()
    time_slept = end_time - start_time
    print("time slept: {} seconds, expected: {} seconds".format(time_slept, time_to_sleep))

    # 4. make request, expecting URL to have expired
    response2 = requests.get(url)
    content2 = response2.content
    self.assertIn("Request has expired", str(content2))    # THIS FAILS (sometimes)
```

Some explanation:

1. `s3.get_file_url(...)` returns pre-signed URL for a file on AWS S3 that expires after the specified 3 seconds. AWS credentials and S3 bucket name are provided within the method/s3-module.
2. Download the file via that URL and check that the file contains what it's expected to contain.
3. Sleep long enough (far longer than should be necessary) for URL to expire.
4. Make request to same URL, expecting the URL to have expired. **This is where the test case *sometimes* fails.** I am expecting XML content that contains the string "Request has expired", but instead I still get the actual file contents.

To be clear: When a pipeline has failed I click the retry button on the gitlab web interface and it may work - no code whatsoever has changed!

What I've done:

1. increase the `time_to_sleep = expiration * 10` to no avail
2. measuring the actual `time_slept` as seen in the code above (output confirms 12+ seconds)

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: "python:3.6.4"

before_script:
  - pip3 install pipenv
  - pipenv install --dev

test:
  script:
  - TESTING=True pipenv run coverage run --source=myapp -m unittest discover -s myapp
  - pipenv run coverage report | grep TOTAL
  tags:
  - unittesting
```

Some (very doubtful) speculations:

1. the `requests` package somehow returns a cached response to the same URL

   - how would I disable that?
   - why would that not always happen?
2. the 2nd `requests.get(url)` is actually somehow executed before the `time.sleep(time_to_sleep)` returns:

   - can `time.sleep()` somehow be non-blocking?
   - my measurements don't work as expected

I realize this may be a very specific issue with many possible sources of error. Hopefully, another set of eyes or someone who's had a similar issue is able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: EDIT: my issue was unrelated to gitlab-runner

Comment: I've never figured this out. I also haven't looked at this issue in quite a while, so I don't know if this still exists. It's been years... :)